# Hunting in Assassin's Creed Freedom Cry

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

In Assassin's Creed Black Flag: Freedom Cry there is an area where you can sell animal goods. I know you can go out and harpoon sea life but how do you kill animals on land? How do you loot them?

I'm aware that islands have an animal as their native animal that can be hunted but I have no idea where to actually hunt.

Also what should I hunt with? Gun or machete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do you kill Land Animals**

*This can be done by either using your melee weapon (hard) or using your gun on the animal (MUCH EASIER) Simplify find the animal and attack them. With gun, aim at them.*

**How do you loot them**

*Go up to them, and press (O) if you have PS3. I believe it is (B) on Xbox. It is the right button on the XAYB. Keyboards have a different button, just look on your keybindings in options for PC*

**Where do I hunt?**

*Simply look at the map for the are (close up) and it will tell you what animals can be found there. It will also tell the general area of where that animal can be found. Just go there and it should be there*

**Do I use my gun or Machete**

*GUN,GUN,GUN,**GUN***. TRUST ME, ***MUCH EASIER***

Comment: Using Eagle Sight can help spotting them in dense areas.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the run and stab method to be easier on both ammunition and also aiming. The video below is me killing iguanas and rabbits on Tortuga.

Comment: Please can you provide a detailed description of what you're doing in the video. Should it be taken down this answer doesn't contain much else.

Comment: @fredley It's me doing the run and stab method. You don't need much  more information.

Comment: What's the run and stab method?

Comment: @GnomeSlice For PC its holding shift while constantly clicking the left mouse button.